# Sparkup Syntax for repeating more than just a single element?

Tags: vim, sparkup

Say I have this:

```
...
    <li class='tab'><a href="#tabs2-7">7</a></li>
    <li class="tab"><a href="#tab2-8">8</a></li>
...
```

...and I'd like to use [Sparkup](https://github.com/rstacruz/sparkup) in my [editor](http://scribes.sourceforge.net) to add another say 6 tabs...so I run the sparkup command:

```
li.tab > a[href=#tab2-$]{$}*6
```

but it comes out all wrong,

```
    <li class="tab"><a href="#tab2-8">8</a></li>
    <li class="tab">
       <a href="#tab2-1">1</a>
       <a href="#tab2-2">2</a>
       <a href="#tab2-3">3</a>
       ...
    </li>
```

My first thought was that my syntax should have been:

```
(li.tab > a[href=#tab2-$]{$})*6
```

But that did pretty much the same thing...except this time it didn't insert the second number:

```
    <li class="tab"><a href="#tab2-8">8</a></li>
    <li class="tab">
       <a href="#tab2-1">$</a>
       <a href="#tab2-2">$</a>
       <a href="#tab2-3">$</a>
       ...
    </li>
```

Now the range problem (starting at 9 instead of 1) is just a minor annoyance, but what if I want it to repeat the `li` as well as the `a` tag?

And yes, before you go off about it, I am indeed aware that I could create all of this stuff just using a simple for loop; but that wasn't part of the question now was it?

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there:

```
li.tab*6 > a[href=#tab2-$]{$}
```

You want to create 6 `<li>` so that's where you should put your multiplier.

No need to be defensive.

Comment: Sorry man, not everybody thinks it's a useful tool (but I do!)

Comment: I love Sparkup too, saves me so much time when doing damn newsletters. Anyway, my answer was a bit too fast: I didn't fully understand what you wanted to do with the multiplier and `$`. Here, using your first snippet doesn't change the content of `a`: it stays as a `$` and is not incremented. That's weird.

Comment: I just noticed that your editor was Scribes, not Vim. It probably makes a slight difference, here.

Comment: Well it all works off of the bash shell program anyway...I have that installed.  (Unless it's integrated into Scribes which I  I'm not real sure about...)  I use vim too...I just didn't install the plugin to try it out as I'm still looking at another way of configuring it.  With Scribes I just wanted to try something new and see what it was like.